# center porfolio images in responsive website

Tags: html, css

If you look at kikidesign.net, my portfolio website on mobile (I'm working on making my portfolio website responsive), you can notice that the portfolio images are not centered. I tried many things to make it centered on width: 100%, but I couldn't get it to work.

Please take time to look at my website's source code and see if there's anything that needs to be fixed in order to make it centered.

html:

```
<div id="thirds">
    <div class="portfoliotext">
            <h2><span>Portfolio</span></h2>
    </div>
<?php query_posts('cat=16&showposts=2'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="first" class="portfolio_item">
        <?php //get article_image (custom field) ?>
        <?php $image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'portfolio_image', true); ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="centered" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="Artwork" /></a>
        <div class="details">
            <h2 class="detailstext"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        </div>
    </div>    

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
    <div id="second" class="portfolio_item2">
        <img class="centered" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/MoreArtworks.png" />
        <div class="details">
            <a href="<?php echo get_option('home');?>/portfolio"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/RightArrow.png" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#thirds {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
#first, #second, #third {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
}
.portfolio_item {
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
.portfolio_item2 {
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
.details {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 0 auto;
}
#first .details, #second .details {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-duration: 500ms;
    -ms-transition: opacity;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -ms-transition-duration: 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-transition-duration: 500ms;
    transition: opacity;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following to `#first, #second, #third`:

```
#first, #second, #third {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    float:none; /* add this */
    margin:0 auto 20px; /* add this  */
}
```

**Update -** sorry, forgot to add some bottom margin. See update, though you may have worked this out already :)

Comment: thanks! it worked! and I changed the margin to margin: 15px auto; to add space between pictures.

Comment: @KristinaBressler - no probs - my mistake, forgot to add some spacing!  Glad you got it working :)